# storing data in a class property

Tags: matlab

I am fairly new to MATLAB and have just started using classes. I have created and object called TestData, which has four properties. One of these properties is metaData. I also need to use a method called setMetaData that will add meta data to the object.

Now, the metaData propery ought to be an Nx2 cell array of name-value pairs. I am having tremendous difficulty getting this to work. I assume I would need to use the method to generate an array and then place that array into the property, correct? In other words, I have not found anything that leads me to believe that the property itself can be "type-casted" as an array prior to the method implenting that.

Secondly, I just don't know how to get strings (the name of the name-value pair) into a single array column. Below is some code that I have written, but please remember that I am very new to this!

Thank you for all the help in advance.

```
classdef TestData
properties
    metaData   %stores meta data in Nx2 array
    data       %stores data in PxQ array
    colLabels  %labels columns
    colUnits   %provides units
end
methods
    function metaArray = setMetaData(name, value)
        metaArray = TestData;


    end


end
```

end

Comment: "an Nx2 cell array of name-value pairs". Why not a struct? You can do `metaData.(name)=value`. It will make it easier to look up the values: `metaData.(name)` returns the value. You can use `isfield` to determine if a given name is present in the struct.

Comment: Okay, I have come to a point where I realize what you are saying is, in fact, what I am looking for. Except would I still do this in a function? I would still  need to initialize metaData as an array correct? I.e. `function this = TestData()` `this.metaData = [];` `end` I know that this might seem trivial, but I am confused as to how MATLAB knows when to initialize an array as a cell array vs. a numeric array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The array will automatically be initialized to an empty array, since you don't explicitly initialize anything in the `properties` section. With an empty array, you can assign in different ways and MATLAB will convert the array to the right type: `metaData{1}=[]` will convert the uninitialized `metaData` into a cell array; `metaData.(name)=[]` will convert the uninitialized `metaData` into a struct array; etc.

Comment: Well, the way I structured the code is similar to how Andrew did it below; that is, I have a method section that contains a constructor `this = TestData()`  and initializes `this.metaData = []` So just for my own clarification, what I have done is made an array of type `TestData` Now, at this point it is still not a cell array, correct? so then I have another function `this = setMetaData(this, name, value)` within this function I set `this.metaData{N,1} = name` and this is where I begin a cell array. I tried `metaData.name = value` within that function and it does not work. I am wrong. Where?

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error message? An unexpected result? If `name='bla'`, then `metaData.name=0` will be different from `metaData.(name)=0`. The former creates or assigns to the `name` field, the second to the `bla` field.

Comment: I run in the CW `myTestData = TestData` to create an object of the class. Then I run 'myTestData = myTestData.setMetaData('temp', '32')' The result is `myTestData = TestData wit properties...` Again the function is: `function this = setMetaData(this, name, value)` `metaData.name = value` `end`

Comment: Again, you want to use `metaData.(name) = value`, with the parenthesis, because you want to use the contents of `name` as a field name, not `name` itself. Then, type `myTestData.metaData` and see what it shows.

Comment: Ah, also, within this function, it should be `this.metaData.(name)=value`.

Comment: Nice! It is up an running. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this for the class definition;

```
classdef TestData

properties
    metaData   %stores meta data in Nx2 array
    data       %stores data in PxQ array
    colLabels  %labels columns
    colUnits   %provides units
end
methods

    %Class constructor 
    function this = TestData()
        this.metaData=[];
    end

    function this = setMetaData(this, name, value)     
        N  = size(this.metaData,1) + 1;
        this.metaData{N,1} = name;
        this.metaData{N,2} = value;
    end
end

end
```

and then to try the class out...

```
myTestData = TestData;

myTestData = myTestData.setMetaData('A', 123);
myTestData = myTestData.setMetaData('B', 567);

myTestData.metaData
```

Comment: Hi there! This definitely worked; however, when I try to instantiate another function I get the error: "'TestData' is already defined as a method in the 'TestData' class. I think I can see why, but then again if I want to add data to another property (such as the 'data' property) I should be able to, right? So, to clarify, here is the code I want to add:                                                   
        `function dataArray = TestData()`
           `dataArray.data = [];`
        `end % dataArray`

Comment: Not completely clear what you want to achieve but I think you want to get access to the data property of the TestData class. You can directly access it, i.e. in my above example you can do myTestData.data = randn(10,10). Usually with classes you want to create a wrapper function (like the setMetaData above) to control access to the property.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out! Thank you. It was simply a matter of adding `this.data = [ ]` to the TestData function. I'd like to ask, though, why do you need to have `this` placed within the arguments of the setMetaData function? It is nothing that is passed in, right? But it must be passed in implicitly?

Comment: Every time you create an instance of a matlab class (similar to python) it does not create a new set of instance methods to itself. So instance methods lie within the class object, which saves memory. So the “this” variable is used behind the scenes to pass the data associated with that instance around.